# snackbar causes crash on android jeally bean

Tags: android

I used snackbar in my code but it gives exception :-

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020068 a=-1 r=0x7f020068} .
```

While it works fine on android lollipop.

Code for Creating custom snackbar :

```
private void browsingOption()
{

    final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(imvBrowse, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    // Get the Snackbar's layout view
    Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
    // Hide the text
    TextView textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    // Inflate our custom view
    View snackView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.browse_option, null);
    // Configure the view
    TextView tvGallery = (TextView) snackView.findViewById(R.id.option_tv_gallery);
    TextView tvCamera = (TextView) snackView.findViewById(R.id.option_tv_camera);
    TextView tvCancel = (TextView) snackView.findViewById(R.id.option_tv_cancel);

    tvGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mayRequestLocation()) {
                openGallery();
            }
            snackbar.dismiss();
        }
    });

    tvCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mayRequestLocation()) {
                openCamera();
            }
            snackbar.dismiss();
        }
    });

    tvCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            snackbar.dismiss();
        }
    });
    // Add the view to the Snackbar's layout
    layout.addView(snackView, 0);
    // Show the Snackbar
    snackbar.show();
}
```

Comment: have you used coordinator layout in your xml file?

Comment: post your xml file

Comment: Have you used an ?attr or something else in a drawable within your layout?

Comment: put the xml file of the layout browse_option